# Hidden option to edit tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Spotted in one of the questions, applies everywhere:

[image]

Notice the white area to the right of all tags.

Hover over this area, and you get a secret option revealed:

[image]

Is it an Easter egg from StackOverflow team?

Comment: That's been around for ages...

Comment: @zzzzBov: It's funny case I only noticed it now. Don't you find it bad UX? Possible solutions - have it almost unnoticable, then fade in color on hover OR leave a > arrow to the right of the tags, which expands to show this option on hover. I am sure there are more options to make this "hidden" option more apparent.

Comment: "Don't you find it bad UX?" not at all. It doesn't distract from the actual tags, which is good for most users who simply read SO. It's readily available for the power users. For beginners, the `edit` button will suffice, as all the same functionality exists on the edit screen.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Yeah, that's how I've been editing tags for a while.

Comment: @Neolisk: that retag link is part of the 10k privs. You'd have discovered it earlier if that wasn't the case, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not an easter egg.

When you reach a reputation of 10,000 you get the privilege [access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

The features available are:

> - View deleted posts
> - Cast delete and undelete votes on questions
> - Access moderator tools
> - **Edit tags inline**

(emphasis is mine)

Further down the privilege page you find the explanation about the inline tag edit feature and its use:

> Hover your mouse next to the tags and you should see a "edit tags" button.
>   This allows you to quickly retag questions that need it, which you'll find especially useful combined with the list of new tags on the stats page.

I use that feature extensively if I help out in burnination or re-tag efforts asked here on meta.