# Bug resurfaced: Can't edit question - title already exists

Tags: discussion, edits

The fix to not fire the duplicate title check for **edits which do not touch the question's title** (mentioned in the accepted answer to this question: [I can't edit a question when the title already exists, but I can ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106911/i-cant-edit-a-question-when-the-title-already-exists-but-i-can-ask)) is no longer working. Also reported in a more recent comment to that answer.

I just hit it today. Reproducible: try to just remove the unrelated `google-app-engine` tag from this question: [This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316056/this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-from-a-background-thread-wh).

Is there a recommended approach to work around the bug?

Update:

I did see [Can't edit question - title already exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288001/cant-edit-question-title-already-exists), but:

- I'm asking for a **recommended** workaround :)
- that OP doesn't seem to have reached a consensus and it's really
  cluttered with stuff related to actually touching the title, so IMHO
  it's unclear where it is heading...

Comment: [Can't edit question - title already exists](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288001/cant-edit-question-title-already-exists)

Comment: For a workaround, try, well, editing the title to make it unique. But yes, I agree that this is a bug: edits that don't change the title should not trigger this check.

Comment: @CoolGuy: saw that, but it doesn't seem to have reached a consensus and it's really cluttered with stuff related to actually touching the title, so IMHO it's unclear where it is heading...

Comment: What did @JonClements do? Just an edit tags?

Comment: I was wondering if there's a difference between "edit" and using the "edit tags" which pops up when hovering next to the tags...

Comment: Seems to be quite a [popular title](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+title%3A%22This+application+is+modifying+the+autolayout+engine+from+a+background+thread%2C+which+can+lead+%22)

Comment: @JonClements: no wonder I didn't notice it - 10k+ rep only feature :) see Matt's comment to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251522/hidden-option-to-edit-tags

Comment: @JonClements: your approach is a possible workaround, should be an answer IMHO.

Comment: I still believe it is a bug, post title, post body and post tags are stored as separate events in the posthistory. You should be able to submit those seperately.

Comment: @rene: rather rare, tho', I have been able to just remove tags so far, this was the 1st time when I hit it.

Comment: So tags are separate, but body and title are checked together. Hmm.

Comment: @theB: Well, it's the beginning of an error-message, so that's to be expected.