# "Question with this title already exists" while editing same question

Tags: bug, edits, error-message

I'm trying to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476915/this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-from-a-background-thread-wh) to add some more relevant tags.

However when I click save, i'm getting an error saying

> A question with this title already exists, be more specific

[image: can't edit error screenshot]

Looks like a bug to me, any ideas?

Comment: I think I've seen this before on Meta

Comment: Ah-ha: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308738/bug-resurfaced-cant-edit-question-title-already-exists

Comment: @Pekka웃 odd, didn't find that one and it wasn't suggested to me. So is this a known issue then? i.e. is it being worked on

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin It's a known issue, yes. But I doubt it's being worked on at this time.

Comment: @MartinSmith that was just a bit of sarcasm. I understand the error, but it seems to be a bug that someone could ask the question without facing this, but I can't edit it because of this issue

Answer (score 1):

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316056/this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-from-a-background-thread-wh) with the same title already. So the real question is not: why am I seeing this error message, but why didn't the system detect this when the question was posted?

Comment: Also, while you're editing the question: an error message of such length should be in the *body* of the question, not the title.