# Is the Excel-VBA tag going to be removed soon or not?

Tags: discussion, tags

It has been pending removal more than a year now, and the past days there is one user who is on a spree to remove the tags off questions, which also results in the questions are bumped to the top.

I asked him to stop and he said he would but I guess the temptation is too great.
This user has done 12 more since he said he would stop and 10 of them is within an hour.
It's probably a badge this user is chasing.

Can we just delete the tag if that's what is supposed to happen or just do something, it's really annoying to read through a full question and answer and realize it's several months old.

Comment: _"It has been pending removal more than a year now"_ Can you point us to the burnination process justifying that the tag should be removed please?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace it's written in all caps when you open the tag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba

Comment: _81,579 questions_ Looks like a big job :-P ...

Comment: Yes and that's what I'm saying. If this user keeps bumping around all those 85000 question it's a big mess in the other tags. For what use? If the tag was suppose to be removed 10-11 months ago then just get on with it so this user will stop messing with the "Active" questions.

Comment: But a _"normal"_ burninaiton process simply includes removing the tags from the question. Anything else I could imagine is that the SO Devs would simply rip it off from the database and run a script to do the removal from the questions. They probably had decided not to do that (yet).

Comment: Yes and that probably means the questions are not bumped, or they are all bumped "now" and in an hour we are back to normal. But with this users actions old questions are always bumped up with the new.

Comment: Tags cannot be deleted other than by removing every usage of them individually.

Comment: I had a complaint about similar behavior (from an anonymous user, which meant everything was going into the Review queue) a while back. The consensus was that removing the tag only made sense *if the excel and vba tags were not already present*. If they were, then no one should be going through to remove just that tag. As I understood it (contrary to a previous comment) removing the tag from existing posts can be done automatically - the only concern being that those other two tags are present...

Comment: I don't visit the review queue a lot, but when I do I routinely reject edits removing the Excel-vba tag or replacing it with the vba tag. Tags will also be added automatically too if the Excel-vba tag gets removed, so these provide no value, and it makes no sense to me to remove a tag now because else it will be removed in the future

Comment: @ErikA agree but this is a 5000 rep point user who can do it themselves.

Comment: What is frustrating about reading through a question *and* answer only to realize they're old? The dates for when it was posted are shown at the top of the page, and if you already know that the question has an answer, then surely you're not upset that you don't have a chance to answer it?

Comment: @TylerH do you always look at the dates when you are looking at the home of Stackoverflow? That page shows the active questions in all tags. Open the question read through it, there was no comments to it, nothing indicating it was an old question (I think it was a 2-3 year old). Then I start building a workbook with the example at hand and composing an answer. I scroll up to look at a detail and notice the date. Yes that is frustrating. And for what? A meta post that said something needs to be done and then it just got left hanging like a Brexit. And because someone is looking for a badge. Mmm

Comment: @Andreas I almost always look at the date yes, especially if I'm potentially interested in answering the question. "There was nothing indicating it was an old question" Yes, *except* the *date it was asked at the very top of the page*. How easy does SO have to make it, eh? I agree with you that the tag just needs to be burninated, but come on. I personally replace the [tag:excel-vba] tag with [tag:excel] and/or [tag:vba] any time I see one, old or new, and you should too. Individuals putting in small persistent efforts is how we get to have nice things.

Comment: Well.. since you ask. Don't bump questions with tag edits. And no I disagree. Let the automated system take care of the removal of tags. There is no need to do that manually. In my opinion there should not be a message in the tag saying not to use the tag, and the thread link should be removed until the system is ready to remove the tag. If it had been a few weeks late then sure, but a year?!

Comment: @Andreas Not bumping questions with tag edits wouldn't make it easier to tell on a question page that the question is old. It sounds like it would just help you cover your forgetfulness/laziness. You literally have to skip over the question's date to get from the title to the body of the question. Also, what automated system? There is no automated system that removes bad tags. It requires users to identify them and then take action. Your final claim reminds me of ex post facto reasoning and wouldn't make sense in any other case, thus doesn't make sense here.

Comment: You have not read the question have you?! Did you just skip past the question to get to the comments section? It's because of a tag edit that the question got bumped to the top! I did not scroll down two three years of questions and opened a question I opened a question at the top of the active questions. If you delete a tag then all questions with this tag will get the tag removed. Kind of obvious.

Comment: Here we go @Tyler. Is this a new or old question? https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6UQK.png no cheating! That is what it looks like. It's on the top of the active page, you see it has been modified, and that is it.

Comment: @Andreas It seems like you're using a mobile app or mobile browser view for that. It's also not the question page view which we've been talking about. Let's try an actual example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIv8J.png

Comment: @TylerH You still don't understand it... https://stackoverflow.com/ is active questions. If that is a question that is asked, answered or modified, then the question will get bumped. THAT IS THE PROBLEM, and that is described in the question here with: ***which also results in the questions are bumped to the top***

Comment: @Andreas No, I understand just fine; you're complaining about the questions list page, but that's a red herring. You need to **visit the question** before you can do anything (including read the actual question), at which point you should immediately see the date the question was asked. That is why it is not an actual problem, especially when you can sort question pages by so many metrics.

Comment: ***when you can sort question pages by so many metrics*** and what metrics would that be, and in what way are they different I respect to this problem?

Comment: @TylerH what metrics can you sort on https://stackoverflow.com/ ? At least have the decency to answer.

Comment: @Andreas I've already shown how to avoid the problem you posited originally; I'm not sure what you're asking now. At least have the "decency" to clearly ask your question.

Answer (score 8):

This was all waiting the launch of saved custom search filters as [Shog9 once indicated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment668862_370095). They recently launched the custom filters so there can be made progress once Shog9 has the time for it, I guess.

Comment: Pretty much this; it's on a list

Comment: How much further did this move down on your list since last august @Shog9?

Answer (score 5):

Bumping this because I am seeing low rep users making edits of just changing [excel-vba] tag to [excel] and [vba]

Should we >2Kers be doing this yet? I have some down time at the moment so I could do this a bit, but don't want to flood the homepage if we shouldn't be doing this yet.

Well I flagged a user who I noticed seemed to be gaming the edits for reputation, admittedly I should've been more descriptive in the flag text. But judging by the response I got I would say this is the go ahead we need to be working on the edits

[image]

Comment: Just for clarity: IIRC, an "Approved" edit that *only* changes tags doesn't earn the user the +2 rep. Is this correct?

Comment: … because I'm getting a *lot* of these in the Suggested Edits queue and I've been approving them, working on that assumption.

Comment: @AdrianMole they will still get the +2 rep

Comment: Interesting - I shall bear that in mind, for future reviews. (But I'm sure I read *somewhere* that 'tag edits' didn't earn rep. - maybe I was dreaming?) (BTW: I know that edits on tag wikis *do* earn rep when approved - even for >2K folks!)

Comment: @AdrianMole this user only has rep from changing these tags https://stackoverflow.com/users/12566016/byte-me?tab=reputation so yeah i think you mightve been dreaming :D

Comment: But still, I judge an edit on its own merits. However, I have noticed, in the course of a daily bash at the ERQ, the same user cropping up repeatedly with the *same* tag add/remove. Particularly common with this Excel-VBA tag, lately.

Comment: @AdrianMole yeah that's the correct approach, I accepted a couple from this user this morning, noticed a pattern, investigated and rejected the next one I saw with a polite message telling him to stop, but I doubt he will see it

Comment: Further to my earlier comment: tag-only edits *do* earn rep. but they don't count towards the Silver/Gold editor badges: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/616624

Comment: Imo we should not be doing this. It makes no sense to me to edit a massive amount of questions only because else they will be edited automatically in the future. I strongly disagree with the decline reason, the fact that this tag will be removed in the future is not a justification why it should be removed now.

Comment: Yes there is no need to do this manually, its a plain waste of time. There are retag tools available to staff members, which minimize the workload drastically.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does an [inline tag edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251522/10871073) (available to 10K+ users) 'bump' the said question? If not, then maybe someone could recruit a "10K Clean-Up Posse?"

Comment: @Adrian I'm quite sure all edits bump the question

Comment: @ErikA ***the fact that this tag will be removed in the future is not a justification why it should be removed now.*** Isn't the problem actually that someone was too trigger happy and posted a post that this tag will be deleted far too early? I don't care much about which tag stays and which goes. But having this kind of mess we have now is just crazy! Always promise less and deliver more. Meaning, don't post that something will happen unless you actually can do it, either with a tool or by hand.

Comment: What's the worry - Only 80,396 question with the excel-vba tag.

Comment: @AdrianMole and with about 1200 per five months it's going to take a lifetime to end this tag. So either end this burnination process or **get things done!**